# Swift - button item iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, image, uibutton, ios11

I created 2 right button item in my navigation Controller. 
Since I updated to iOS 11, the content inset of icons has changed and I really don't know why ...

This this the difference between iOS 10 (Left) and iOS 11 (right):

[image]

Do you have any idea about how I could change that ?

This is a piece of my code :

```
 editButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -30)
```

It was good with this line in iOS 10 ...

Comment: Please show how the bar button items are created.

Answer (score 0):

```
 editButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

iOS 11 set this to `YES` by default, try to set this property, and adjust button:

```
[editButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -30)];
```

Comment: It seems that translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is not working on UIBarButtonItem :/ ( value of type 'UIBarButtonItem' has no member 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' )